# Convert buffer to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, memcached

I am setting `memcached` with

```
$memcached->set("item" , ["1" => "hello"]);
```

anything work in PHP ,

In Node.js with `memcached` plugin , I get a buffer instead of array in result

```
<Buffer 61 3a 25 61 34 3a>
```

I can not convert such buffer to array

In Node.js :

```
memcached.get("item" , function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

Do you have any way ?

Comment: What happens if you just call `$memcached->set("item" , "hello");` in php?

Comment: it get string and no problem

Comment: how about `$memcached->set("item" , ["1", "hello"]);`  I wonder if PHP is not writing the array properly

Comment: I can ge that as array well , may be the php serilize that , also I got array with this code phpjs.unserialize(data.toString());

Answer (score 71):

`arr = [...buffer]`

ES6 introduced a lot of other features, besides buffers.

You can even easily append like this:

`arr.push(...buffer)`

The `...` operator expands enumerables such as arrays and buffers when used in array. It also expands them into separate function arguments.

---

Yes, it's also faster:

> **...** : x100000: *835.850ms*
>
> **Slice call from prototype** : x100000: *2118.513ms*

```
var array,
    buffer = new Buffer([1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 3, 5, 67, 7, 4, 3, 5, 76, 234, 24, 235, 24, 4, 234, 234, 234, 325, 32, 6246, 8, 89, 689, 7687, 56, 54, 643, 32, 213, 2134, 235, 346, 45756, 857, 987, 0790, 89, 57, 5, 32, 423, 54, 6, 765, 65, 745, 4, 34, 543, 43, 3, 3, 3, 34, 3, 63, 63, 35, 7, 537, 35, 75, 754, 7, 23, 234, 43, 6, 247, 35, 54, 745, 767, 5, 3, 2, 2, 6, 7, 32, 3, 56, 346, 4, 32, 32, 3, 4, 45, 5, 34, 45, 43, 43]),
    iter = 100000;

array = buffer;

console.time("... : x" + iter);
for (var i = iter; i--;) array = [...buffer]
console.timeEnd("... : x" + iter);

console.time("Apply/call/etc : x" + iter);
for (var i = iter; i--;) array = Array.prototype.slice.call(buffer, 0)
console.timeEnd("Apply/call/etc : x" + iter);
```

Answer (score 18):

**There is another way to convert to array of integers**

Using **[toJSON()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tojson)**

```
Buffer.from('Text of example').toJSON()
{ type: 'Buffer',data: [ 84, 101, 120, 116, 32, 111, 102, 32, 101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101 ] }

// simple get data
Buffer.from('Text of example').toJSON().data
[ 84, 101, 120, 116, 32, 111, 102, 32, 101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101 ]
```

**Example of benchmark**

```
// I took this from @user4584267's answer
const buffer = new Buffer([1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 3, 5, 67, 7, 4, 3, 5, 76, 234, 24, 235, 24, 4, 234, 234, 234, 325, 32, 6246, 8, 89, 689, 7687, 56, 54, 643, 32, 213, 2134, 235, 346, 45756, 857, 987, 0790, 89, 57, 5, 32, 423, 54, 6, 765, 65, 745, 4, 34, 543, 43, 3, 3, 3, 34, 3, 63, 63, 35, 7, 537, 35, 75, 754, 7, 23, 234, 43, 6, 247, 35, 54, 745, 767, 5, 3, 2, 2, 6, 7, 32, 3, 56, 346, 4, 32, 32, 3, 4, 45, 5, 34, 45, 43, 43]);
let array = null;
const iterations = 100000;

console.time("...buffer");
for (let i = iterations; i=i-1;) array = [...buffer]
console.timeEnd("...buffer");

console.time("array.prototype.slice.call");
for (let i = iterations; i=i-1;) array = Array.prototype.slice.call(buffer, 0)
console.timeEnd("array.prototype.slice.call");

console.time("toJSON().data");
for (let i = iterations; i=i-1;) array = buffer.toJSON().data
console.timeEnd("toJSON().data");
```

**OUTPUT**

> ...buffer: **559.932ms**
>   array.prototype.slice.call: **1176.535ms**
>   toJSON().data: **30.571ms**

**or if you want more profesional and custom function in Buffer use this:**

```
Buffer.prototype.toArrayInteger = function(){
    if (this.length > 0) {
        const data = new Array(this.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i=i+1)
            data[i] = this[i];
        return data;
    }
    return [];
}
```

**Example of benchmark:**

```
const buffer = new Buffer([1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 3, 5, 67, 7, 4, 3, 5, 76, 234, 24, 235, 24, 4, 234, 234, 234, 325, 32, 6246, 8, 89, 689, 7687, 56, 54, 643, 32, 213, 2134, 235, 346, 45756, 857, 987, 0790, 89, 57, 5, 32, 423, 54, 6, 765, 65, 745, 4, 34, 543, 43, 3, 3, 3, 34, 3, 63, 63, 35, 7, 537, 35, 75, 754, 7, 23, 234, 43, 6, 247, 35, 54, 745, 767, 5, 3, 2, 2, 6, 7, 32, 3, 56, 346, 4, 32, 32, 3, 4, 45, 5, 34, 45, 43, 43]);
let array = null;
const iterations = 100000;

console.time("toArrayInteger");
for (let i = iterations; i=i-1;) buffer.toArrayInteger();
console.timeEnd("toArrayInteger");
```

**Ouput:**

> toArrayInteger: **28.714ms**

**Note:** In the last example I copied a function from [Buffer.toJSON](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3c277d7e92adf1464e41d27677fcdc05fec41a2b/lib/buffer.js#L979) and custom it a lite

Answer (score 11):

Here you go:

```
var buffer = new Buffer([1,2,3])
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(buffer, 0)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Could you add a little more detail to your answer? Thanks!

Comment: What additional detail is needed?!

Comment: Super concise answer that works! Thanks I was struggling to read the silly paragraphs.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used memcached so I am not sure just what this buffer represents or what you want to have instead. Sorry. Here is a function to split a buffer up into an array of bytes. More at [node.js Buffer docs](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end), hope it helps!

```
var hex = new Buffer("613a2561343a", "hex");
var l = hex.length; // in bytes
var output = [];
for(var i = 0; i < l; i++){
  var char = hex.toString('hex',i,i+1); // i is byte index of hex
  output.push(char);
};
console.log(output);
// output: [ '61', '3a', '25', '61', '34', '3a' ]
```

Comment: it just split the buffer data , it do not convert each item to used character

Comment: Gotcha. Maybe there is a way to make PHP save a non-encoded string into memcached? I don't know either very well, sry - good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
memcached.get("item" , function(err, data) {
  console.log(Array.from(data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, although I am currently trying to find a better one:

```
function bufToArray(buffer) {
  let array = new Array();
  for (data of buffer.values()) array.push(data);
  return array;
}
```

**EDIT :** I found a simpler way:

```
var buffer = Buffer.from('NodeJS rocks!')
var array = new Function(`return [${Array.prototype.slice.call(buffer, 0)}]`)
```

But, like someone already said, `[...buffer]` is faster (and more code efficient).

You can also use `new Uint8Array(buffer [, byteOffset [, length]]);`

Comment: 'a simpler way' is eval which is totally uncalled-for here.

Comment: Why in the world do you need a function constructor?? Is it more performant or in any way better than `var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(buffer, 0);`?

Answer (score -3):

In interent , there was no information about that , but I have found the convert way

In nodejs , I have to use :

```
var arrayobject = phpjs.unserialize(data.toString());
```

but , it is very stupid way for getting array , it seem that php serilzie the data when setting memcache .

Comment: You could try to store the array as JSON.  `$memcached->set("item" , json_encode(["1" => "hello"]));`.  Then decode the JSON in node.js.

Comment: Yes , that is way , but think we get high rate on encode decode per sec , in such way , that is not efficent way